# Regex Find Specific Character Between Characters of the Same Type

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I am looking to change all , between groups of `¨¨` untouching everything else between the `¨¨`.

I think I am almost there, but it grabs , between all `¨¨` (not grouping them)

```
Regex yourRegex2 = new Regex(@"(?<=\¨[^¨]*),(?=[^¨]*\¨)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
string allData = yourRegex2.Replace(allData1, "»");
```

Code above used on this example `2,¨5,3,6¨,1,2,1,¨3,4¨,1,2` grabs all the commas from `¨5,3,6¨,1,2,1,¨3,4¨` and not just between the groups `¨5,3,6¨` and `¨3,4¨`

Sorry if this has been gone over before, but I have been looking and searching and cannot fine the right way to code this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Did you mean to have non-standard double quotes in your data?

Comment: This code replaces all , with » it is replacing between all sets of ¨ insead of groups of  ¨. I am looking to grab all commas between groups of ¨ with digits and characters. so when it hits ¨test,this¨,1,2,4,"9,8" it will only grab the , between test,this and 9,8

Comment: I replaced standard quotes with nonstandard to make it easier coding. Really doesn't matter what character it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your code asserts that what is on the left is `¨` and then 0+ times not `¨` and match a comma. After that assert that what is on the right is a `¨`.

That is valid for all the above comma's where a `¨`  is on the left and on the right.

But what you might do for your example data is to match a digit after `¨`

```
(?<=¨[0-9][^¨]*),(?=[^¨]*\¨)
     ^^^^^
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%c2%a8%5b0-9%5d%5b%5e%c2%a8%5d*%29%2c%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%c2%a8%5d*%5c%c2%a8%29&i=2%2c%c2%a85%2c3%2c6%c2%a8%2c1%2c2%2c1%2c%c2%a83%2c4%c2%a8%2c1%2c2) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/dQT0cY)

[image]

If it should work not only for digits, you might use:

```
(?<=¨[^¨]+),(?=[^¨]*[^¨]\¨)
```

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%c2%a8%5b%5e%c2%a8%5d%2b%29%2c%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%c2%a8%5d*%5b%5e%c2%a8%5d%5c%c2%a8%29&i=3%2c2%2c%c2%a8test%2ctest%c2%a8%2c2%2c%c2%a83%2c4%c2%a8)

If it should work not only for digits, you might use:

```
(?<=¨[^¨,][^¨]*),(?=[^¨]*[^¨,]¨)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `[^¨,]` Match not `,` or `¨`
  - `¨[^¨]*` Match `¨`, then 1+ times not `¨`
- `)` Close positive lookbehind
- `,` Match literally
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[^¨]*¨` Match 1+ times not `¨`, then match `¨`
  - `[^¨,]` Match not `,` or `¨`
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%c2%a8%5b%5e%c2%a8%2c%5d%5b%5e%c2%a8%5d*%29%2c%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%c2%a8%5d*%5b%5e%c2%a8%2c%5d%c2%a8%29&i=4%2c4%2c%c2%a8meal%2c+card%c2%a8%2c4%2c4%2c%c2%a89%2c9%c2%a8%2c+%c2%a89%2c3%2c5%2c3%2c5%2c3%c2%a8) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/vYUrTL)

[image]

Comment: @CLWorker Do you mean like this? `(?<=¨[^¨]+),(?=[^¨]*[^¨]\¨)` See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%c2%a8%5b%5e%c2%a8%5d%2b%29%2c%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%c2%a8%5d*%5b%5e%c2%a8%5d%5c%c2%a8%29&i=3%2c2%2c%c2%a8t%2ct%c2%a8%2c2%2c%c2%a83%2c4%c2%a8)

Comment: say this was the example 4,4,¨meal, card¨,4,4,¨9,9¨ this one grabs the commas between ¨meal, card¨,4,4,¨9,9¨ I only need the ones between ¨meal, card¨ and ¨9,9¨

Comment: @CLWorker Like this then `(?<=¨[^¨,][^¨]*),(?=[^¨]*[^¨,]¨)` [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%c2%a8%5b%5e%c2%a8%2c%5d%5b%5e%c2%a8%5d*%29%2c%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%c2%a8%5d*%5b%5e%c2%a8%2c%5d%c2%a8%29&i=4%2c4%2c%c2%a8meal%2c+card%c2%a8%2c4%2c4%2c%c2%a89%2c9%c2%a8%2c+%c2%a89%2c3%2c5%2c3%2c5%2c3%c2%a8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `Regex` to match:

1. Standard double-quotes:

   ```
   Regex regex = new Regex(@"\"(.+?)\"", RegexOptions.Compiled);
   ```
2. Special double-quotes:

   ```
   Regex regex = new Regex(@"¨(.+?)¨", RegexOptions.Compiled);
   ```

It matches one or more characters between your target string.

Then, use `Regex.Matches` which will match all such occurrences:

```
var data = "2,¨5,3,6¨,1,2,1,¨3,4¨,1,2";
var result = regex.Matches(data);
```

`result` will have both `¨5,3,6¨` and `¨3,4¨`.
[image]

If you want to replace, simply use `Regex.Replace()` and it will replace all such occurrences.

```
var final = regex.Replace(data, "»");
```

Contents of `final` variable:

> 2,»,1,2,1,»,1,2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant to use regular double quotes and not special quotes (otherwise why the incorrect `\` escapes?), use the lambda version of `Regex.Replace`:

```
Regex yourRegex2 = new Regex(@"""[^""]*""", RegexOptions.Compiled);
string allData = yourRegex2.Replace(allData1, m => m.Value.Replace(",","»"));
```